# Inception V3 CoreML translate language of output label

Tags: swift, xcode, coreml

I'm using the Inceptionv3.mlmodel CoreML model but would like to translate the output labels to multiple languages. What's the cleanest / best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [built in internationalization / localization features](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html) in iOS.  Simply get a list of all the output labels, and create localization string files for each language you wish to translate.

Comment: How did you get a list of all possible outputs?